# SEO оптимизация мультиязычной сайта

Tags: mvc, seo, i18n, мультиязычность

Имеется собственный фреймворк, который способен получить некоторые данные по IP-адресу пользователя, а именно диапазон IP и стран, которые привязаны к текущему листу IP адресов из чего можно узнать список языков и основной язык страны пользователя.

Цель стоит в создании мультиязычного сайта.

Изначально логика работы задумывалась следующая.

Пользователь делает запрос, по его IP получаем страну и язык страны записывает в куки, либо сессию, после чего отдаем пользователю HTML код с текстом на его языке, пользователь так же может сменить язык сайта на любой доступный заменив данные в сессии \ куки.

Логика довольно проста. Но насколько это дружелюбно сказывается с SEO? Индексируют ли поисковики подобные сайты с разными языками, либо же нет альтернативы кроме как:

```
example.com - основной язык, скажем английский
example.com/ru - второстепенный язык, русский
example.com/de - немецкая версия сайта
```

с редиректом пользователя на нужную версию языка сайта, которую пользователь так же сможет изменить изменив куки / сессию.

Хотелось бы ещё привести пример на примере сайта `vk.com`.

У VK нет ссылка на язык сайта /ru, /eng, /de и т.д, но при этом, если зайти не из русскоязычной страны, то язык будет выбран автоматически (к примеру английский), так же в англоязычном google'e сайт индексируется именно на английском языке, в русском же google'e сайт индексируется на русском. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: отправил английский гугл-бот Accept-language=en в запросе и получил английский ответ

Answer (score 0):

**[Со стороны Гугл ваша реализация может иметь негативные последствия](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#geotargeting)**:

> Не показывайте различные варианты контента в зависимости от IP-адреса
> посетителя. Определить таким образом местоположение нелегко, и этот
> метод неточен. Кроме того, это может затруднить сканирование вариантов
> вашего сайта для Google. Большинство роботов Google запускается из
> США, и мы не пытаемся указывать другие местоположения, чтобы
> обнаружить разные версии сайта.